# How do I get panels to show up on the same layer in winform C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am docking all my panels to the windows frame but unfortunately either one panel shows up over the other. Instead it would be nice to dock all the panels so they share the same layer (z-index) and are not on top of each other. Thanks for any help.

Comment: if you do not put the panels side by side, say one docked left and the  other one docked client (remaining space), how are you thinking to see both at same Z index? imagine the two panels as two paper sheets, if you overlap them, one must always be on top, or you do not overlap and there will be same Z index but not same area taken (side by side)

Comment: I thought that they would automatically share the same area like divs. I have one panel that is docked at the top, but it needs to also re-scale vertically. The only way to get that behavior is to dock fill instead which ends up making the panels overlap. Ultimately I want two panels to dock top with only one of those panels scaling vertically.

Comment: Set the last of the two panels to Dock.Fill, this will then be placed below the one which is docked on top, and filling the vertical space

Comment: I tried that and one panel is always on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- you can use `Anchor` property and `Anchor` topmost panel `Left`, `Top` and `Right` and lower panel on all four sides
- you can put yet another panel and `Dock` it as `Bottom` and then `Dock` the middle panel as `Fill` and it will take the remaining space
- you can use `TableLayoutPanel` and make 3 rows

Use View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline for better overview of what is happening